# how to calculate the different between start date and end date with out holidays ? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, momentjs

how to return the different of days between 2 dates with out including holidays and weekend .

i have done the weekend

```
export const workday_count = (start: moment.Moment, end: moment.Moment) => {
 const first = start.clone().endOf('week');
 const last = end.clone().startOf('week');
 const days = (last.diff(first, 'days') * 5) / 7;
 let wfirst = first.day() - start.day();
 if (start.day() === 6) --wfirst;
 let wlast = end.day() - last.day();
 if (end.day() === 5) --wlast;
 return wfirst + Math.floor(days) + wlast;
} ;
```

,but now i need to calculate the different with out holidays ,

for example i have

`const holidays=['2021-1-13','2021-1-14','2021-1-15','2021-1-16','2021-1-17','2021-1-18']`

and the start date is `'2021-1-10'` end date is `2021-1-20` so the total days is 4 days .

Answer (score 0):

Here I find out solution for you.

```js
function getBusinessDateCount (startDate, endDate) {
    var elapsed, daysBeforeFirstSaturday, daysAfterLastSunday;
    var ifThen = function (a, b, c) {
        return a == b ? c : a;
    };

    elapsed = endDate - startDate;
    elapsed /= 86400000;

    daysBeforeFirstSunday = (7 - startDate.getDay()) % 7;
    daysAfterLastSunday = endDate.getDay();

    elapsed -= (daysBeforeFirstSunday + daysAfterLastSunday);
    elapsed = (elapsed / 7) * 5;
    elapsed += ifThen(daysBeforeFirstSunday - 1, -1, 0) + ifThen(daysAfterLastSunday, 6, 5);

    return Math.ceil(elapsed);
}

function calc() {
  let start = document.querySelector('#startDate').value,
      end = document.querySelector('#endDate').value,
      result = getBusinessDateCount(new Date(start), new Date(end));
  document.querySelector('#result').value = result;
}
```

```html
Start date: <input type="date" id="startDate" value="2020-01-04"><br>
End date: <input type="date" id="endDate" value="2020-01-06"><br>
<input type="button" onclick="calc()" value="Get business days"><br>
Business days: <input id="result" readonly>
```

Comment: thank you , but this will handle the weekend , i already handle weekend , but i want to handle the holidays dates

Comment: const holidays=['2021-1-13','2021-1-14','2021-1-15','2021-1-16','2021-1-17','2021-1-18']
holidays.map((item) => {
if(item.isBetween(startDate, endDate)) {
// here you can subtract the 1 from calculated numbers of days. Hope so it will help you
}
})